# RHEL 9 in Docker container on macOS: subscription-manager is disabled when running inside a container

Tags: redhat, mac-osx, rhel8

I'm attempting to use RHEL 9 via the `redhat/ubi9` Docker image, having redhat individual developer subscription. However, on attempt to use `subscription-manager`, got this error message: `subscription-manager is disabled when running inside a container. Please refer to your host system for subscription management.`.
Am I supposed to configure something on macOS level, or configure in container itself?

For RHEL 8 image (`redhat/ubi8`) everything works well.

Answer (score 6):

All you need is just a `return False` from `in_container()`, See https://github.com/candlepin/subscription-manager/blob/subscription-manager-1.28.32-1/src/rhsm/config.py#L105-L114:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi

ARG REDHAT_USERNAME
ARG REDHAT_PASSWORD

RUN sed -i 's/\(def in_container():\)/\1\n    return False/g' /usr/lib64/python*/*-packages/rhsm/config.py
RUN subscription-manager register --username $REDHAT_USERNAME --password $REDHAT_PASSWORD --auto-attach
RUN yum update -y
RUN subscription-manager unregister
```

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi

ARG REDHAT_USERNAME
ARG REDHAT_PASSWORD

RUN sed -i 's/\(def in_container():\)/\1\n    return False/g' /usr/lib64/python*/*-packages/rhsm/config.py
RUN subscription-manager register --username $REDHAT_USERNAME --password $REDHAT_PASSWORD --auto-attach
RUN yum update -y
RUN subscription-manager unregister
```

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi

ARG REDHAT_USERNAME
ARG REDHAT_PASSWORD

RUN sed -i 's/\(def in_container():\)/\1\n    return False/g' /usr/lib64/python*/*-packages/rhsm/config.py
RUN subscription-manager register --username $REDHAT_USERNAME --password $REDHAT_PASSWORD --auto-attach
RUN yum update -y
RUN subscription-manager unregister
```

Comment: You can also just remove the symlink /etc/rhsm-host: `rm /etc/rhsm-host`

Answer (score 1):

> For RHEL 8 image (redhat/ubi8) everything works well.

It looks like redhat updated ubi8 too, same problem occurs with `8.7-929`.
`8.6-990` is working okay, for now downgrading to that one is a possible workaround.

Unfortunately, Redhat changed the way subscription managers work in containers:
[See their official documentation on running ci/cd inside ubi containers](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/cicd/builds/running-entitled-builds.html)

[Thread on redhat forums discussing this change:](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5889431)

Someone mentioned using
`ENV SMDEV_CONTAINER_OFF=1`
In the dockerfile for a possible workaround. That didn't work for ubi8, maybe you can try for ubi9 and see it it fixes it.
Unfortunately, this is also just a workaround... as far as I can see, the only real fix is to run the container on a registered RHEL machine (since the container now takes the subscription info from the host).

This really is a shame, redhat basically butchered the ubi images with this move... Having a container be bound to a specific host OS seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: [`SMDEV_CONTAINER_OFF` is only available starting with subscription-manager 1.29.14](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5889431#comment-2354194). But [Wong Hoi Sing Edison's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1116296/58568) seems to work in the meantime.